# Изменить метод фреймворка KIImagePager

Tags: objective-c, activityindicator

Пытаюсь изменить стиль UIActivityIndicatorView у фреймворка, но не получается дотянуться до этого индикатора, подскажите как можно изменить его стиль? Классы в самом фреймворке менять не хочется, может через категории как-то: пытался переопределить метод в категории, но успехом это не завершилось. Фреймворк называется KIImagePager, нужно изменить индикатор в методе loadData (можно посмотреть этот метод по ссылке - https://github.com/kimar/KIImagePager/blob/master/KIImagePager/KIImagePager/KIImagePager.m)
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ну если категория/сабкласс не подходит, то можно поменять нужный метод на свой в рантайме посредством method swizzling. вот туториал http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему с помощью appearance, вот решение кому нужно будет:

[[UIActivityIndicatorView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[KIImagePager class], nil] setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];